# Xamarin.Forms: Multiple Subuser Profile page

Tags: forms, xamarin, mobile, layout, profile

I'm trying to create a Profile Page for my app that contains information about manny Subusers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlwhV.jpg "Desing"

As you can see in the imgur link, It should have a different image, binded details and a button that goes to another detail page for that specific user.

In the top add or edit current user.
And in the sides next previous button to switch between subUsers.

I´m not sure what layout should work. I wanted to use a stackLayout but it does snot contain a `ItemSource` Property to set the binding.

Im also worries about the user id for the buttons, not sure if I should use some sort of `BidingParameter`

This is the code for my view so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.ProfilePage"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:App.Converters"
             Title="Profile">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:DateTimeToStringConverter x:Key="converter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <!--<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Edit" 
                     x:Name="New" 
                     Command="{Binding NewCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                     >
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Save" 
                     x:Name="Save" 
                     Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    ></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>-->
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Profile"></Label>
            <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="250" >
                <Image Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200"/>
                <Label   Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,12,0,0">
                <Label Text="Detail1: "></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Detail1}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <Label Text="Detail2: "></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Detail2}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <Label Text="Detail3: "></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Detail3, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <Label Text="Detail4: "></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Detail4}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <Label Text="Detail5: "></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Detail5}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My viewModel will load a list of subusers

```
 public void UpdateSubUsers()
     {
        List<Subuser> Subusers= new List<Subuser>();
        LoadSubuser(Subusers);
        if (SubuserList != null)
        {
            SubuserList.Clear();
            foreach (var subin Subuser)
            {
                SubuserList.Add(sub);
            }
        }
     }
```

Logic xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class ProfilePage : ContentPage
     {
        public ProfilePageVM viewModel;
        public ProfilePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new ProfilePageVM();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            viewModel.UpdateDogs();
         }
        }
```

Currently, I´ve setted my list to return one item only but I´m not able to display it in the screem.
Also I´m not sure how can I manage the pagging of the subuser while staying in th Profile Tab. (refer to image).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlwhV.jpg "Desing"

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my reply. You could download the source file in MultipleSubuser folder from the GitHub.

https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

**ProfilerListPage.xaml**

It is the mail page to show the Name of the list of all users.

**ProfilerListPage.xaml.cs**

It used to binding the list and when the item was selected, it would navigate to the profiler page and pass the selected item data to the profiler page.

```
 private void LstView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as ProfilerViewModel;
        var index = e.SelectedItemIndex;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage(index));
    }
```

**ProfilePage.xaml**

It is the profiler page,  when you select the item in ProfilerListPage, this page would show all the details of selected User.

```
   <ImageButton x:Name="btnBack" Margin="0,0,60,0" BackgroundColor="White"  Clicked="BtnBack_Clicked" Source="Back.png" WidthRequest="40"  HeightRequest="40" ></ImageButton>
   <ImageButton x:Name="btnNext" Margin="60,0,0,0" Clicked="BtnNext_Clicked" Source="Next.png" WidthRequest="40" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" ></ImageButton>
```

**ProfilerPage.xaml.cs**

I use two buttons(tbnBack, btnNext) to load previous or next item.

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How would you manage that theres a List of Subusers, the binding should start at the first element and the arrows (in the picture I uploaded) should load the next one the list.

Comment: I have updated my reply. You could download from GitHub.

Comment: Hello, Im still having issues with this topic. https://imgur.com/gallery/nI9shCw?s=wa

Comment: I beleive theres a problem with the biding of my elements. From the list of buttons I beleive that the objects are passing trought the viewmodel to the view. But its forming a list instead of showing one element at a time while waiting for the user to switch between subusers. Would you mind if I share access to my project on Github so you can take a better look? Maybe im missing something.

Comment: @Jd996 For this case, you could close with the answer. After that, you could open a new thread with the sample code and new requirement.